# Recommendation on probability and statistic books.

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm currently starting to self study probability and statistic, a friend recommend me to use a book he has but his book does not go deep in the theorem and formula, instead it just state the equation and when to use it along with some properties but not the proof for the equation (for example: the chapter about the Poisson random variable just tells you how to use it and when, but lacks the proof of how mathematicians arrive at that complex equation ). I would like a book that is rigorous and proof-based for every problem in it ( like Tom M. Apostol's calculus books for example), im a colleague student and has good calculus and linear algebra background so an more advance than regular books is ok with me. Do you have any recommendation ?

Comment: *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications* by Feller

Comment: *Basic Probability Theory* of Robert B. Ash is a good starting point to learn probability theory rigorously. However the knowledge needed for a serious attempt to learn statistics is larger and I don't know a good reference for an introductory, and rigorous book, on statistics (rigorous here means that every theorem is proved)

Comment: A rigurous treatment of probability would require measure theory, which is quite advanced as it requires at least some knowledge of functional analysis. However, Ash's book and Feller's book are good enough, the former proving what he cans and outlining what he can't and the latter being formal for the discrete theory of random variables.

Comment: I second Ash's "basic" probability -- its basic only insofar as it doesn't develop probability using measure theory. However, he uses borel sets, sigma-algebras, etc liberally it it stops about as close as you can get to measure theoretic probability without going all the way. Oh, and the book has answers at the end of the book :)

Comment: Surprised no one has said Grimmett and Sitrzaker

Comment: Since you said you are interested in probability *and* statistics, you might consider a book on mathematical statistics, e.g. *Introduction to Mathematical Statistics* by Hogg.

Comment: *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis* by John A. Rice. Everything except advanced theorems is proved. Measure theory is not required. Multivariable calculus is required, of course. Linear algebra is used only in the chapter on linear regression.